# Pass function as prop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a `onSelection` function to a component:

```
 const GenderScreen = (props) => {

  const onSelection = () => {console.log('clicked')};

  const buttons = ['one','two', 'three'];
  const breadcrumb = `${i18n.t('stage 1')} > ${i18n.t('stage 2')} > ${i18n.t('stage 3')}`;
  const sceneConfig = {
    centredButtons: ['one','two', 'three'],
    question: {
      text: [breadcrumb, i18n.t('What is your ethnicity?')],
    },
    selectNumber: {},
    onSelection: this.onSelection
  };
  return <SceneCentredButtons  { ...props} sceneConfig={sceneConfig} />;
};
```

Child component:

```
const SceneCentredButtons = props => (
  <LYDSceneContainer goBack={props.goBack} subSteps={props.subSteps}>
    <Flexible>
      <LYDSceneQuestion {...props.sceneConfig.question} />
      <LYDCentredButtons
        {...props.sceneConfig}
        onSelection={props.sceneConfig.onSelection}
      />
    </Flexible>
  </LYDSceneContainer>
);



function LYDCentredButtons(props) {
  const buttons = this.props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      {props.centredButtons.map((button, i) => {
        const isLast = i + 1 === props.centredButtons.length;
        const marginBottomStyle = !isLast && {
          marginBottom: theme.utils.em(1.5),
        };
        return (
          <LYDButton
            style={[styles.button, marginBottomStyle]}
            label={button.text}
            onPress={() => props.onSelection(button.value)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

However, when in my component I get the error:

**props.onSelection is not a function**

How can I pass a function to use when my buttons are clicked?

Comment: are you sure that the props you passed contains your onSelection Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenderScreen` is a stateless functional component, you don't need to use `this` keyword (this will be undefined).

So instead of `this.onSelection` use `onSelection`.

Like this:

```
const sceneConfig = {
    centredButtons: ['one','two', 'three'],
    question: {
      text: [breadcrumb, i18n.t('What is your ethnicity?')],
    },
    selectNumber: {},
    onSelection: onSelection
};
```